# one process terminates and other completes i/o simultaneously

Tags: operating-system, scheduler

I encountered this question in my Operating Systems class test. The question says:

> Consider there are three processes P0, P1, P2 running on a system where P2 has the highest priority. Currently process P1 is in the running state, P0 is waiting in the ready queue and P2 is doing the I/O operation. Assume, in the next timestep, P1 terminates and P2 completes I/O simultaneously. List step by step all the events that will take place before the next process gets allocated to the CPU. Assume system implements a preemptive priority CPU scheduler.

My doubt is, since P1 terminates and P2 completes I/O simultaneously, what exactly will happen first.

> Will the scheduler schedule P0 from the ready queue and then P2 will get added to the ready queue followed by the preemption of P0?

OR

> will P2 go to the ready queue from the I/O queue and then Scheduler will schedule among P2 and P0?

Comment: why not post it on http://cs.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @sanjayk79 because cs.stackexchange.com has less operating system followers than on stackoverflow.com. :P

Comment: When the I/O completes it should call an interrupt handler immediately, which puts P2 back in the ready queue; the CPU would then continue where it left off in P1's call to exit(), cleans up, and picks the next process to run, which should then be P2.